# How to display values in a drop down in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have implemented 2 drop downs as below

[image]

When Select a category from the first drop down, according to the selected value, it will assign values to the second drop down list.

But when the applications is started for the first time, first drop (Select Category) down won't display any value. If select the second drop down (Select Item) and then when I click on the first drop down, all the values are assigned. What could be the issue?

Below is the implementation

component.html

```
        <div class="row ml-3 mr-3 mt-3">
            <label class="col-form-label">Select Category :</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedItemType" (ngModelChange)="selectItemType()">
                <option value="" [selected]="true"> Please choose one </option>
                <option *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="row ml-3 mr-3 mt-5">
            <label class="col-form-label">Select Item :</label>
            <select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedItemName" (ngModelChange)="selectItemName()">
                <option value="" [selected]="true"> Please choose one </option>
                <option *ngFor="let selectedItem of selectedItems">{{selectedItem.itemName}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, SimpleChange} from '@angular/core';

import { DashboardService} from "@modules/dashboard/services";
import {element} from "protractor";

@Component({
  selector: 'cashier',
  templateUrl: './cashier.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cashier.component.scss']
})
export class DashboardItemsComponent implements OnInit {
    items : String[];
    selectedItems : {itemName : String, price : number}[] = [];
    addedItems : {itemName : String, quantity : number, price : number}[] = [];
    selectedItemType : String = ''
    selectedItemName : String = ''

  constructor(
     private dashboardService : DashboardService
  ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.dashboardService.getItems()
                .subscribe(response => {
                    this.items = response    //<-------- this will retrieve values for first drop down from the backend API
                })
        }, 1000)

      console.log(this.items)
  }

  selectItemType(){
     let tempSelectedItems : {itemName : String, price : number}[] = [];
        this.dashboardService.getItemsByType(this.selectedItemType)
            .subscribe( response => {
                for(let item of response){                   //<-------- this will retrieve values for second drop down from the backend API
                    tempSelectedItems.push({itemName : item.itemName, price : item.price})
                }
                this.selectedItems = tempSelectedItems;
            })
  }

  selectItemName(){
        console.log(this.selectedItemName)
  }


  add(){
        //implentation
  }
}
```

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import {map} from "rxjs/operators";
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class DashboardService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getDashboard$(): Observable<{}> {
        return of({});
    }

    getItems(){
        return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/rest/items/types')
            .pipe(map(items => {
                if(items){
                    return items;
                }
            }))
    }

    getItemsByType(type){
        let tempSelectedItems : {itemName : String, price : number}[] = [];
        return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:8080/rest/items/itemsByType', {params : { itemType : type}})
            .pipe(map( items => {
                if(items){
                    // return items;
                    for(let i of items){
                        tempSelectedItems.push({itemName : i.itemName, price : i.price})
                    }

                    return tempSelectedItems;
                }
            }))
    }
}
```

Comment: First issue because the initial value of `selectedItemType` in empty. Provide the code for `selectItemName`method  to analyze second issue.

Comment: I tried to repeat your problem, but in my implementation all was ok: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gtjlte?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: didn't get any error : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bnstt5?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I have implemented nothing in ```selectItemName``` method. Just a console log. I will update the question providing the ```selectItemName``` method. Can you please check? @uiTeam324

Comment: but in my browser it gives me this issue! @programoholic :( :( :( :(

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console? Why have you used setTimeout for firing getItems()? Should not be required.

Comment: No there are no errors. Initially I thought this happens because of a delay of getting data. That's why I add the setTimeout. Yet this problem continues @Nayak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any issue with code, and if you look at the stackblitz posted, they seem to work.

So I would suggest you to strip down the code to the minimum and start from there.

```
<div class="row ml-3 mr-3 mt-3">
    <label class="col-form-label">Select Category :</label>
    <select class="form-control">
       <option value=""> Please choose one </option>
       <option *ngFor="let item of items">{{item}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Start with only the above code in the template and see if it works. We can continue from there.

Note: setTimeout is not required. Please remove that and use it only when utmost necessary.

Update 1:

```
constructor(
 private dashboardService : DashboardService,
 private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dashboardService.getItems().subscribe(response => {
      this.items = response;
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); // This should be used temporarity until the actual issue is located.
  });
}
```

Note 2: Do not use String, Number, Boolean as Types. In it's place, use string, number, boolean
Ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html

Comment: Okay once I tried in this way, same situation continues. When I click some where in the browser (white space) it will load and display the data

Comment: So for sure, the UI update lifecycle hook is not getting triggered. Did you remove the setTimeout()? If it's still not working, then your issue  is somewhere else. Till the actual issue is found, you can temporarily inject ChangeDetectorRef in constructor, and fire this.changeDetectorRed.detectChanges() when you set this.items = response;

Comment: I will try to find the real issue. And the suggested way is working. Thanks for helping!

Comment: One additional thing to remember. Do not use String, use string